# installing php .deb files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef, deb, dotdeb

I am using dotdeb.org php 5.4.8 
http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/squeeze/php5/5.4.8/binary-amd64/

I download all the files on to my box and run the following

```
cd /tmp/php-deb-5.4.8
dpkg -i php5-common_5.4.8-1~dotdeb.0_amd64.deb
dpkg -i --force-depends *.deb
apt-get install -f
```

I am running this box on ec2 and using my chef recipe for installation but the problem is i get an error

```
Processing triggers for php5-fpm ...
* Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager php5-fpm                                                                                                                                 [fail] 
Errors were encountered while processing:
php5-mysql
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install the packages manually. You had to explicitly ignore a bunch of warnings telling you to not do what you just did or things would break, and that's why it isn't working.

To fix the problem, follow the [instructions](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) to add dotdeb.org to your apt sources, and then use `apt-get` to install the desired packages.

Comment: Michael, I am booting into the cloud and would like to install a specific version of packages. This is to prevent from upgrades that may break things, since everything is automated and I don't have a traditional colo where the server is always up and running, or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: If you need specific versions, use apt pinning. And for the love of all that is good, don't ignore dependencies. You really do need them.